# Dealing with non-existent methods in external jars

Tags: java

I have an application in which I am referencing an external library. In calling one particular method from an object type in this library some of my clients are getting issues because they do not have this method in their version of this library. I am trying to catch this exception and report it correctly to the User. So I have wrapped the call in a try/catch block but this does not catch it:

```
try
{
    cell.setRowspan(rowSpan);
}
catch (Exception  e)
{
    Throwable throwable = e.getCause();
    throw new Exception(throwable);
}
```

When I try to debug the issue eclipse is just opening up the java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException clas. It does not enter the catch block. What can I do here to correctly catch this issue?

Comment: Catch Errors not exceptions

Comment: You need to catch java.lang.NoSuchMethodError which is not a subclass of Exception.  Just change it to catch Throwable instead of Exception.

Comment: @TampaHaze Thanks yes that is what I needed, I can catch it now

Answer (score -1):

```
catch (NoSuchMethodException e){  
  e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer & format your code properly?

Comment: I had tried this already and it does not solve my problem. The compiler says "Unreachable catch block for NoSuchMethodException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"